# Swift Array append not appending values but replacing it

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, nsarray

I am trying to add some dictionaries into an array and save it using `UserDefaults`, but the problem is the array doesn't append new dictionary but only replaces the dictionary. How can I fix this issue?

here is the code:

```
class Bookmark: NSObject {

     var bookmark: [[String:Any]] = []

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }



    func setBookmark(imageURL:String, title:String, description:String, summary:String, date:String, link:String)  {
        bookmark.append(["imageURL":imageURL , "title":title , "description":description, "summary":summary , "date":date, "link":link])
        UserDefaults.standard.set(bookmark, forKey: "bookmark")

    }


    func getBookrmark() -> [Any] {
        let loadedBookmark = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "bookmark")
        return (loadedBookmark)!
    }

}
```

Using Bookmark class:

```
class ReadViewController: UIViewController  {

    var bookmark = Bookmark()


       func save() {
            bookmark.setBookmark(imageURL: nImageURL.absoluteString, title: ntitle!, description: nDescription.htmlToString , summary: nSummary!, date: nDate!, link: nLink.absoluteString)
        }
```

Comment: Have you *debugged* the problem? What does `bookmark` contain before and after you append something to it? – My guess: You create new instances of the Bookmark class (which start with an empty array).

Comment: @MartinR Correct  :) I have tried to answer it

Comment: Show the code where you are creating `Bookmark` object and calling its methods. I tried it and its working completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information but I can guess you where you have made mistake.

Your class  `Bookmark` is not **singleton** class so,every time  `Bookmark()` create new instance every time. that means it will   create new `bookmark` object  for every instance.

What I suggest you is inside func     `func setBookmark(imageURL:String, title:String, description:String, summary:String, date:String, link:String)`

**Method 1 :** Fetch the latest bookmarks in separate variable and append new object inside it and write to User Default  as well as update the global object

**Method 2** Or you can make it singleton and use shared instance for every time you perform operation.

**Method 3** Another solution can be create global object of `Bookmark` in `AppDelegate` or Your singleton class  and then use that object

However

```
func setBookmark(imageURL:String, title:String, description:String, summary:String, date:String, link:String)  {
        bookmark.append(["imageURL":imageURL , "title":title , "description":description, "summary":summary , "date":date, "link":link])
        UserDefaults.standard.set(bookmark, forKey: "bookmark")

  }
```

This is the bad practice to follow.  You are directly **replacing** User default with new value however your intension is to append new element not replace existing data in userdefault.

You should always fetch latest and update it Like method 1 show as well as If you wanted to fetch the data in userdefault there is no use of your global object      `var bookmark: [[String:Any]] = []` because you have already `getBookrmark` method there

Hope it is clear to you

Comment: @Mc.Lover When you getting issue. Try one thing  in  `ReadViewController` in ViewDidLoad method call save several times and check

Comment: Method 1 worked, I just needed to add this line :    `bookmark = getBookrmark() as! [[String : Any]]` before `append`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using the above code with an example and its working completely fine.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let b = Bookmark()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        b.setBookmark(imageURL: "a", title: "a", description: "a", summary: "a", date: "a", link: "a")
        b.setBookmark(imageURL: "b", title: "b", description: "b", summary: "b", date: "b", link: "b")

        print(b.getBookrmark())
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[{
    date = a;
    description = a;
    imageURL = a;
    link = a;
    summary = a;
    title = a;
}, {
    date = b;
    description = b;
    imageURL = b;
    link = b;
    summary = b;
    title = b;
}]
```

Check if you are using the same way or anything else.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to say,.

Comment: I mean instead add a dictionary with `b` values, it only saves and replaces dictionary with `b`. Not `a` and `b`

Comment: There might be some issue with your code then. Kindly add more code so I can tell the issue,.